# Question about integer number and PID

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

What is the set of all integers that can be written in the form $m^2+2n^2$? Here $m$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Further more, what about $m^2+kn^2$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

I think the first question might has some relation with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a PID? Suppose this set is $A$ I guess if $p$ is a prime number and $p^2\in A$ then $p\in A$ by some specific example. I do not know how to prove this. Maybe the second question has no answer for a random $k$.

Appreciating for every help and idea.

Comment: Well for both you can surely take $A = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. You might want to exclude that example? $A = \lbrace 1 \rbrace$ or $A = \lbrace k \rbrace$ also works.

Comment: @TMO Thank you for your comment, yes I want to have non-trivial conclusion.

Comment: You can also take the set of squares (by taking  $n= 0$ the time) . That is at least already an infinite set. I mean in general you can of course just define $A$ to be the set defined by that property of course but I assume you want some other description or something more concrete?

Comment: Right now your question is "can we find a set of integers that can be written in the form $m^2+2n^2$". That's not a very robust question: you can just take any examples you happen to find, as other commenters have noted. Do you mean "what is the set of all integers that can be written in the form $m^2+2n^2$"? That is a more interesting question.

Comment: @TMO Yes I want to know can we have other descriptions. So I guess if $p$ is a prime number and $p^2\in A$ then $p\in A$, can we prove this?

Comment: @Greg Martin Thanks for your advice, I will correct my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is that there are three kinds of obstructions to an integer not being represented in the form $ m^2 + kn^2 $: Either there is a modular obstruction due to quadratic residues (for instance, $ 5 $ can't be represented as $ m^2 + 2n^2 $ because this would imply $ -2 $ is a quadratic residue modulo $ 5 $, which is false), there is a class group obstruction, or there is an integrality obstruction (the last two are related). When the ring $ \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-k}] $ is a principal ideal domain, which is an exceptional situation that doesn't arise unless $ k = 1 $ or $ k = 2 $, then neither the class group obstruction nor the integrality obstruction exist, and the numbers represented by the quadratic form are precisely those that don't contradict quadratic reciprocity.

For instance, in the case $ k = 2 $, this means a number may be represented as $ m^2 + 2n^2 $ if and only if the exponents of all primes that are $ 5 $ or $ 7 $ mod $ 8 $ (primes modulo which $ -2 $ is not a quadratic residue) in its prime factorization are even. More explicitly, if $ c = \prod_k p_k^{r_k} $ for distinct primes $ p_k $, then $ c $ may be represented in the form $ m^2 + 2n^2 $ if and only if whenever $ p_k \equiv 5, 7 \pmod {8} $, we have $ r_k \equiv 0 \pmod{2} $.

To generalize it to all $ k $ requires an understanding of the class groups of the imaginary quadratic number rings and their orders, which doesn't exist in general, but in specific cases it's possible to apply an algorithm of Gauss (quadratic form reduction) to determine if some specific integer may be represented by some specific quadratic form. It doesn't result in this kind of elegant description, however; essentially because by looking at "actual integers" instead of "ideal integers" (as Kummer described ideals in number rings), you're seeing the arithmetic behavior through a somewhat distorted lens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Suppose $z=p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_s^{r_s}$, $p_i \neq p_j$ for $i\neq j$. So $z$ can be represented as $m^2+2n^2$ if and only if $r_i \equiv 5\ \text{or}\ 7\ \rm{mod} 8$ for each $i$. Do I understand correctly? I do not know how quadratic reciprocity could give us this condition, can you explain more?

Comment: @Deemo That's not the condition. Let me make it more explicit in the answer.

Comment: We just need to ask $p_k \equiv 5,7\ (\rm{mod}\ 8)$ for k which $r_k$ is even. Do I understand correctly this time? I am still thinking how quadratic reciprocity could give us this condition, can you explain some details or reference？

Comment: @Deemo No, you have to ask that $ r_k $ is even for k which $ p_k \equiv 5, 7 \pmod{8} $. Your implication is backwards. As for "some details", just look at the splitting behavior of primes downstairs in $ \mathbf Z $. With the principal ideal domain condition, you know any prime which splits does so into principal elements, so the rest of the proof is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you so much.